# C++17: non-const reference to temporary from method returning *this

Tags: c++, c++17, rvalue-reference

I'm sure this has been asked before, but my googling skills weren't sufficient to find my case. Simply put, is the following valid C++ code?

```
struct A {
    int a;

    static A foo() { return {5}; }
    A& bar() { return *this; }

    A(A&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    A& a = A::foo().bar();
    a.a = 7;
    return a.a;
}
```

Normally, I should only be allowed to store const references to temporaries, but I'm unsure if C++17 relaxed this. I tried to read the specification, but got confused.

clang, gcc and msvc seem to able to compile this, but gcc breaks with O2 if I remove `a.a = 7;`: https://godbolt.org/z/n7vGT44Y5.

Comment: This is a dangling reference, regardless of const.

Comment: You should bind `A::foo()` not `A::foo().bar()`to a const reference.

Comment: NB: it doesn't compile in c++20 because `A(A&)` is deleted, I am still trying to figure out why it compiles at all in c++17...

Comment: @Fluffy: [aggregate (initialization)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) changes from version to version. In particular, presence of *user-declared constructors*.

Comment: @Fluffy `A` is an _aggregate type_ in C++17, but not in C++20. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/WWK6E3cxc. The difference is that `A::A(A&)` constructor is _user-declared_, but not _user-provided_.

Answer (score 2):

`bar()` doesn't return temporary, it returns reference.

`A::foo()` returns a temporary, its lifetime ends at end of full expression.
so `a` is a dangling reference.